# How do i store a selection of a image to variable JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, variables, canvas, save

I'm making an HTML 5 game and I have a sprite sheet image.
How can I select parts of that image and store them to a variable so that they can later be drawn using the canvas?

Comment: Why do you want to copy it to a variable?

Comment: To variables? You should be assigning them to classes of an element.

Comment: Do you want to copy the actual pixels/image data, or coordinate sets?

Comment: Okay so instead of writing each time `context.drawImage(SpriteSHEET, x, y, w, h, animationsData[0].positionX, animationsData[0].positionY, 170, 122);` i want to just do `context.drawImage(spritevar, 1,1);` and the problem is that i dont know how to get the selection from a spritesheet and store it to a var

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to 'cut' your spritesheet into an array of canvas.
The ith canvas of this array contains the ith image of your spritesheet.
You call getSheet with the spritesheet image + the number of images your animation
contains :

```
   function getSheets(img, imgCount) {
       var sheets = [];
       var sheetWidth = img.width/imgCount, sheetHeight=img.height;
       for (var i=0; i<imgCount; i++) {
           var newSheet = document.createElement('canvas');
           newSheet.width=sheetWidth; newShit.height=sheetHeight;
           var ctx = newSheet.getContext('2d');
           ctx.drawImage(img,i*sheetWidth,0,sheetWidth,sheetHeight,0,0,sheetWidth,sheetHeight );
           sheets.push(newSheet);
        }
       return sheets;
    }
```

from this point your can store this array in the object than hold the animation (or the animated entity directly):

```
myObject.sheets = getSheets(animationImage, 6);
```

then use with

```
context.drawImage(this.sheets[sheetIndex],x,y);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I been trying to do since a month ago, just wasn't sure how.